# HTML5 - stop wrapping

Tags: html

I've tried suggestions from other answers like, white-space: wrapnow;, nothing's worked so far. My question is, how do I stop the wrapping of text in HTML?

The text on the navbar moves out of position as I minimize my browser, how do I stop this om happening?

Here's a [pic of the problem](http://prntscr.com/1vvu8i)...

My CSS

```
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu {
    margin-top: -8px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; right: 0; left: 0;
    text-align: left;

    background: rgb(63,76,107); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%, rgba(63,76,107,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(63,76,107,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(63,76,107,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3f4c6b', endColorstr='#3f4c6b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #000000;

    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}

.menu li a { /* Navigation Bar text */
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;

    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3); */

    -webkit-transition: color .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .4s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:first-child a{ border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }
.menu li:hover > a { text-decoration: underline; }
.menu li#navbar-logo:hover > a { text-decoration: none; }

.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(63,76,107,1);

    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #393942;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .75s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .75s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .75s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .75s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .75s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
}

.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 35px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    margin: 0;

    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}

.menu ul li:last-child a {
    border: none;
}

.menu li#navbar-logo,
.menu li#navbar-about,
.menu li#navbar-shop,
.menu li#navbar-contact,
.menu li#navbar-community {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu li#navbar-logo {
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.menu li#navbar-logo,
.menu li#navbar-about,
.menu li#navbar-shop,
.menu li#navbar-contact,
.menu li#navbar-community {
    margin-left: -13px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.menu li#navbar-about,
.menu li#navbar-shop,
.menu li#navbar-contact,
.menu li#navbar-community {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#navbar-logo a{
    color: #FFC8C8;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: Intrique Script Personal Use;
}
```

The HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title of Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li id="navbar-logo"><a href="#">Arc Studios</a></li>
                <li id="navbar-about"><a href="#">About Us</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ's</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Inception</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="navbar-shop"><a href="#">Store</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">OS's</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="navbar-contact"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help Centre</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="navbar-community"><a href="#">Community</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <br></br>
    <footer class="footer">
        <p><small>&copy; Copyright Arc Innovations 2013, All rights reserved</small></p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself

Comment: Ok ill re-edit it now

Comment: I don't see any text being wrapped in your image.

Comment: He probably means the menu links breaking to a new row but that is very hard to analyze without the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like this?

```
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It would be easier to debug with a http://www.jsfiddle.net example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `white-space: nowrap;` should work.